# Histogram and Gaussian fitting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, gaussian, data-fitting

I have a problem with my long script, and I hope to get an answer there.
I have a 2D histogram and I would like to fit it by a Gaussian. However, I would like to remove lot of data in my numpy array because there is noise. This noise is shifting my Gaussian and it's causing an error.

I reproduce my script with this little example in order to see easier where is situated the problem :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import random

list = np.array([0.1,0.258,0.259,1.536,1,0.99,0.24,2.1,0.32,0.8,0.7569,0.963,0.6544,0.785])  # initial array

list_2 = list > 0.3         # New array, for exemple only values which are > 0.3



plt.figure(1)
plt.hist(list)
plt.xlim((min(list), max(list)))

mean = np.mean(list)
variance = np.var(list)
sigma = np.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(min(list), max(list),100)
plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x,mean,sigma))




plt.figure(2)
plt.hist(list_2)
plt.xlim((min(list_2), max(list_2)))

mean2 = np.mean(list_2)
variance2 = np.var(list_2)
sigma2 = np.sqrt(variance2)
x2 = np.linspace(min(list_2), max(list_2),100)
plt.plot(x2,mlab.normpdf(x2,mean2,sigma2))

plt.show()
```

But, when I plot it, I obtain this kind of figures (it's not what I want) :

[image: Initial list]
[image: After condition]

So, I don't know why I lost lots of values, even more than 0.3.
It's the same problem with my original script, the range of my values are between 0 and 2 with lot of noise between 0 and 0.1 than I would like remove in order to get a good fitting.

Hopfully I was clear,

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the mask with the masked data.

```
data = np.array([1,2,3])
mask = data > 2
print(mask)
# array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

And then you make a histogram of these boolean values: But `True` is interpreted as `1` and `False` as `0`.

What you wanted is to apply the mask before plotting the histogram:

```
print(data[mask])
# array([3])
```

So in your case, if you only want to keep those values which are above 0.3 you need to do instead of:

```
# list_2 = list > 0.3
list_2 = list[list > 0.3]
```

but I would recommend not using `list` as a variable name since there is a [built-in class](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-list) with the same name. With the changed line the histogram looks more like it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you to your answer ! Yes I was confusing between mask and mask data. In my case, it's the second solution which let to get what I want so thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

@MSeifert's answer already does fix your question to fit an univariate gaussian to your data. However, the histogram you show in the question cannot be modelled properly with a single gaussian (as the plot of @MSeifert shows).

It might be redundant to your question, but you can get better visualization (and modelling properties) by fitting either a kernel density estimate or a multivariate gaussian (or mixture of gaussians) to your data.

A quick example to do so using [seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/):

```
import seaborn as sns

list_2 = list_1[list_1 > 0.3]

plt.figure()
sns.distplot(list_2, kde=True, rug=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Note** the renaming of `list` to `list_1`. You should never shadow data types in python.

Comment: I really like your answer but his [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016693/fitting-a-gaussian-to-a-histogram-with-matplotlib-and-numpy) is probably fittable by an univariate gaussian.

Comment: @MSeifert yep, I didn't know about that answer. Your answer is the one that actually answers the OP question. I was just pointing him towards other directions in case there was a more general question behind it.

Comment: In fact, my data represent almost perfectly a gaussian when I plot histogram. So I don't need to get more than one Gaussian curve to fit it ;)
But, I didn't know that it was possible with seaborn to do that ! So thanks